# JavaScriptの絞り込みがうまく動かない

Tags: javascript

こういった絞り込みを実装してみたくて、以下のサイトをそのままコピーしてindex.htmlを作ってみたのですが、うまく動きません。ご教示いただけないでしょうか？
https://www.tam-tam.co.jp/tipsnote/javascript/post14636.html

```js
 var searchBox = '.search-box'; // 絞り込む項目を選択するエリア
var listItem = '.list_item';   // 絞り込み対象のアイテム
var hideClass = 'is-hide';     // 絞り込み対象外の場合に付与されるclass名

$(function() {
    // 絞り込み項目を変更した時
    $(document).on('change', searchBox + ' input', function() {
        search_filter();
    });
});

/**
 * リストの絞り込みを行う
 */
function search_filter() {
    // 非表示状態を解除
    $(listItem).removeClass(hideClass);
    for (var i = 0; i < $(searchBox).length; i++) {
        var name = $(searchBox).eq(i).find('input').attr('name');
        // 選択されている項目を取得
        var searchData = get_selected_input_items(name);
        // 選択されている項目がない、またはALLを選択している場合は飛ばす
        if(searchData.length === 0 || searchData[0] === '') {
            continue;
        }
        // リスト内の各アイテムをチェック
        for (var j = 0; j < $(listItem).length; j++) {
            // アイテムに設定している項目を取得
            var itemData = $(listItem).eq(j).data(name);
            // 絞り込み対象かどうかを調べる
            if(searchData.indexOf(itemData) === -1) {
                $(listItem).eq(j).addClass(hideClass);
            }
        }
    }
}



/**
 * inputで選択されている値の一覧を取得する
 * @param  {String} name 対象にするinputのname属性の値
 * @return {Array}       選択されているinputのvalue属性の値
 */
function get_selected_input_items(name) {
    var searchData = [];
    $('[name=' + name + ']:checked').each(function() {
        searchData.push($(this).val());
    });
    return searchData;
```

```css
 .search_item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.search_item.is-active {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
.is-hide {
    display: none;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="search-box">
            <span class="search-box_label">種類:</span>
            <input type="radio" name="kind" value="">ALL
            <input type="radio" name="kind" value="野菜">野菜
            <input type="radio" name="kind" value="果物">果物
        </div>
    
        <div class="search-box">
            <span class="search-box_label">色:</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="赤色">赤色
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="緑色">緑色
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="黄色">黄色
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="赤色">いちご 種類: 野菜 色: 赤色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="黄色">かぼちゃ 種類: 野菜 色: 黄色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="緑色">キャベツ 種類: 野菜 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="赤色">さくらんぼ 種類: 果物 色: 赤色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="緑色">すいか 種類: 野菜 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="緑色">キウイ 種類: 果物 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="黄色">バナナ 種類: 果物 色: 黄色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="緑色">メロン 種類: 野菜 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="赤色">りんご 種類: 果物 色: 赤色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="黄色">レモン 種類: 果物 色:黄色 </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 参考先の Web サイトでは jQuery を使用しているため、 jQuery を読み込む必要がありますが、質問者さんのコード内では読み込まれていません。
2. 参考先のコードと質問文のコードを読み比べると、質問文のコードは CSS と JavaScript のコードの下部の記述が欠けているため、正常に実行が行われていません。

以上の二点を修正すると以下のようになり、絞込み機能が参考先の Web サイトのように動作していることが確認出来ます。

```js
var searchBox = '.search-box'; // 絞り込む項目を選択するエリア
var listItem = '.list_item';   // 絞り込み対象のアイテム
var hideClass = 'is-hide';     // 絞り込み対象外の場合に付与されるclass名

$(function() {
    // 絞り込み項目を変更した時
    $(document).on('change', searchBox + ' input', function() {
        search_filter();
    });
});

/**
 * リストの絞り込みを行う
 */
function search_filter() {
    // 非表示状態を解除
    $(listItem).removeClass(hideClass);
    for (var i = 0; i < $(searchBox).length; i++) {
        var name = $(searchBox).eq(i).find('input').attr('name');
        // 選択されている項目を取得
        var searchData = get_selected_input_items(name);
        // 選択されている項目がない、またはALLを選択している場合は飛ばす
        if(searchData.length === 0 || searchData[0] === '') {
            continue;
        }
        // リスト内の各アイテムをチェック
        for (var j = 0; j < $(listItem).length; j++) {
            // アイテムに設定している項目を取得
            var itemData = get_setting_values_in_item($(listItem).eq(j), name);
            // 絞り込み対象かどうかを調べる
            var check = array_match_check(itemData, searchData);
            if(!check) {
                $(listItem).eq(j).addClass(hideClass);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * inputで選択されている値の一覧を取得する
 * @param  {String} name 対象にするinputのname属性の値
 * @return {Array}       選択されているinputのvalue属性の値
 */
function get_selected_input_items(name) {
    var searchData = [];
    $('[name=' + name + ']:checked').each(function() {
        searchData.push($(this).val());
    });
    return searchData;
}

/**
 * リスト内のアイテムに設定している値の一覧を取得する
 * @param  {Object} target 対象にするアイテムのjQueryオブジェクト
 * @param  {String} data   対象にするアイテムのdata属性の名前
 * @return {Array}         対象にするアイテムのdata属性の値
 */
function get_setting_values_in_item(target, data) {
    var itemData = target.data(data);
    if(!Array.isArray(itemData)) {
        itemData = [itemData];
    }
    return itemData;
}

/**
 * 2つの配列内で一致する文字列があるかどうかを調べる
 * @param  {Array} arr1 調べる配列1
 * @param  {Array} arr2 調べる配列2
 * @return {Boolean}    一致する値があるかどうか
 */
function array_match_check(arr1, arr2) {
    // 絞り込み対象かどうかを調べる
    var arrCheck = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) >= 0) {
            arrCheck = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return arrCheck;
}
```

```css
.search_item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.search_item.is-active {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
.is-hide {
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="search-box">
            <span class="search-box_label">種類:</span>
            <input type="radio" name="kind" value="">ALL
            <input type="radio" name="kind" value="野菜">野菜
            <input type="radio" name="kind" value="果物">果物
        </div>
    
        <div class="search-box">
            <span class="search-box_label">色:</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="赤色">赤色
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="緑色">緑色
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="黄色">黄色
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="赤色">いちご 種類: 野菜 色: 赤色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="黄色">かぼちゃ 種類: 野菜 色: 黄色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="緑色">キャベツ 種類: 野菜 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="赤色">さくらんぼ 種類: 果物 色: 赤色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="緑色">すいか 種類: 野菜 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="緑色">キウイ 種類: 果物 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="黄色">バナナ 種類: 果物 色: 黄色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="緑色">メロン 種類: 野菜 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="赤色">りんご 種類: 果物 色: 赤色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="黄色">レモン 種類: 果物 色:黄色 </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！Jqueryの記述でした！